# Generating Fractals with transformation matrices

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, fractals

I'm trying to generate fractals using five different transformations that I have implemented from skeleton code, translate, rotate, scale, non-uniform scale, and image. These transformations are all 3x3 matrices, for example:

```
Matrix rotate ( Pt p, float theta )
{
    Matrix rvalue;
    rvalue.data[0][0] = cos(theta);
    rvalue.data[0][1] = -sin(theta);
    rvalue.data[0][2] = p.x + p.y*sin(theta) - p.x*cos(theta);
    rvalue.data[1][0] = sin(theta);
    rvalue.data[1][1] = cos(theta);
    rvalue.data[1][2] = p.y - p.y*cos(theta) - p.x*sin(theta);
    rvalue.data[2][0] = 0;
    rvalue.data[2][1] = 0;
    rvalue.data[2][2] = 1;
    return rvalue;
}
```

where Matrix is defined as

```
class Matrix
{
    public:
    float data [ 3 ] [ 3 ];

    Matrix ( void )
    {
        int i, j;

        for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
            {
                data [ i ] [ j ] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In a test file, there is the following code that is supposed to generate [Serpinski's Triangle](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&docid=pmR6IznDB9jjXM&tbnid=xgMYBw85f8qv9M%3a&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=https://www.zeuscat.com/andrew/chaos/sierpinski.html&ei=_cgMU5-aJajf2QXWw4CAAw&bvm=bv.61725948,d.aWc&psig=AFQjCNE0_2jHvd4A3TTdS-666_6n6pBKrA&ust=1393433211400826)

```
vector<Matrix> iat;
iat.push_back ( scale ( Pt ( -.9, -.9 ), 0.5 ) );
iat.push_back ( scale ( Pt ( .9, -.9 ), 0.5 ) );
iat.push_back ( scale ( Pt ( 0, .56 ), 0.5 ) );

setIATTransformations ( iat );
```

Where Pt is defined as:

```
class Pt
{
public:
    float x, y;

    Pt ( float newX, float newY ) 
    { 
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }

    Pt ( void ) 
    { 
        x = y = 0;
    }
};
```

How should I implement setIATTransformations? Multiply the matrices until there is one transformation matrix and loop it a number of times to generate the fractal?

Answer (score 0):

you want sierpinski triangle or fractal generator driven by input script ?

1.triangle

- is easy enough
- no rotations translations or what so ever are needed
- just create the points according to sierpinski rule http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle
- all sides of triangles are divided to half
- so the new points are just average of start and end point of each line
- and then fill the sub triangles
- if you want just wire-frame then even the point list is not needed

2.generator

- you did not provide any rules,commands for the control script
- the only thing I see in your script is input of the 3 vertexes of the triangle
- and that is all
- I do not see any rule for triangle division
- or which part is filled or not
- how many recursions are used
- the only thing you mentioned was that you use 5 transformation matrices 3x3 for rotation,scale and translation
- but did not specify when and why

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement the chaos game. That is, you randomly select one of the transformations and apply it to the iteration point. Do it a number (30, 50 or 100) without painting the point and after that mark all the points. The resulting point cloud will in time fill the fractal.

Your operation scale( Pt (a,b), s) should realize the operation

(x',y')=s*(x,y)+(1-s)*(a,b), that is, in matrix terms

```
| x' |   |  s  0  (1-s)*a|   | x |
| y' | = |  0  s  (1-s)*b| * | y |
| 1  |   |  0  0    1    |   | y |
```